# Had to install wifi driver every time after rebooting my system

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Every time time I open my Ubuntu system, the enable wifi option just disappears and I have to use this command every time`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it is not the installation of bcmwl-kernel-source that is the problem, but loading the resultant module. First, see if it is inadvertently blacklisted:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. If the line 'blacklist wl' is present, remove it. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Now, let's get the module to load automatically:

```
sudo -i
echo wl  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: It worked.Thanks.Can you please tell me what exactly was that 'blacklist wl' line doing?

Comment: The line 'blacklist wl' was blocking the exact driver your wireless device needs to work properly.